# Salesforce Compile Error: Expression cannot be assigned at line -1 column -1

Tags: error-messages, error

I'm getting the error message that is the title of this question. I don't see any documentation for this error and my google searches don't reveal anyone else running into it either. Any guidance?

```
public class EventFieldUpdates {

public static void updateEvent(List<Event> events) {
    // Get the recordtypeid for planning opportunities
    String recordTypeIdPlanning = ([SELECT id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Planning' LIMIT 1]).get(0).Id;
    String currentYear = String.valueof(System.Today().year());
    Map<Event, Opportunity> eventOppMap = new Map<Event, Opportunity>();
    List<String> eventIds = convertToIdList(events);
    List<Opportunity> opportunities = [SELECT AccountId, StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE Planning_Year__c >= :currentYear AND RecordTypeId = :recordTypeIdPlanning AND AccountId IN :eventIds];
    Opportunity relatedOpp = null;

    // Sort the Opportunities by Event Id
    List<OpportunitySortable> sortableOpps = new List<OpportunitySortable>();
    for(Opportunity opp:opportunities) {
        sortableOpps.add( new OpportunitySortable(opp) );
    }
    sortableOpps.sort();

    // Build Map of events to their correct opportunities. 
    for(Event event:events) {
        // Search for the opportunity related to this event by year and eventid
        relatedOpp = findRelatedOpportunity(event, sortableOpps);
        eventOppMap.put(event, relatedOpp);
    }

    // empty the list of opportunities and re-use it for storing the opportunities that need to be updated 
    opportunities.clear();

    // for each event in the map, get its opportunity and update it if necessary
    for(Event event:eventOppMap.keySet()) {
        Opportunity opp = null;
        if( event.Activity_Type__c == 'Sizing Appointment' ) {
            opp = eventOppMap.get(event);
            // Only update the stagename if the opportunity is in one of these stages
            if( opp.StageName == 'VS-Planning' || opp.StageName == 'VS-Planning Complete' || opp.StageName == 'VS-Contact Complete' ) {
                opp.StageName = 'VS-Fitting Booked';
            }
            opportunities.add(opp);
        }
        else if( event.Activity_Type__c == 'Consultation/Pre-Sale' ) {
            opp = eventOppMap.get(event);
            // Only update the stagename if the opportunity is in one of these stages
            if( opp.StageName == 'VS-Planning' || opp.StageName == 'VS-Planning Complete' || opp.StageName == 'VS-Contact Complete' ) {
                opp.StageName = 'VS-Meeting (Consultation) Booked';
            }
            opportunities.add(opp);
        }
    }
    update(opportunities);



    // Legacy Code that was here prior to 11/15/2013. Must've been written by Chuck Toler - Ethan Willis
    if(event.StartDateTime !=null){
        event.Copy_of_Start__c=event.StartDateTime;
    }
    if(event.EndDateTime !=null){
        event.Copy_of_End__c=event.EndDateTime;
    }
}
```

/*
       Helper inner classes and methods
   */

```
// Finds the correct opportunity for the given event
public static Opportunity findRelatedOpportunity(Event event, List<OpportunitySortable> opps) {
    // Implement iterative binary search later
    Opportunity opp = null;
    for(OpportunitySortable o : opps) {
        if( o.relatedToEvent(event) ) {
            opp = o.getOpp();
        }
    }
    return opp;
}

public static List<String> convertToIdList(List<SObject> objs) {
    List<String> ids;
    for(SObject so : objs) {
        ids.add( so.Id );
    }
    return ids;
}

public class OpportunitySortable implements Comparable {
    public Opportunity opp;
    public String oppAccount;

    public OpportunitySortable(Opportunity opp2) {
        opp = opp2;
        oppAccount = opp2.AccountId;
    }

    //implement comparable methods.
    public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        OpportunitySortable compareOpp = (OpportunitySortable)compareTo;
        Integer compareValue = 0;
        String compareOppAccount = compareOpp.AccountId;

        compareValue = oppAccount.compareTo(compareOppAccount);

        return compareValue; 
    }

    // check if this opportunity is the one that belongs to an event
    public Boolean relatedToEvent(Event event) {
        Boolean relatedTo = false;
        String eventId = event.Id;
        String eventYear = String.valueOf(((event.EndDateTime).year()));
        // check if this opportunity has a matching year and accountid to the given event
        if( opp.Planning_Year__c == eventYear && opp.Accountid == eventId ) {
            relatedTo = true;
        }

        return relatedTo;
    }

    public Opportunity getOpp() {
        return opp;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I waited about 30 minutes and kept clicking save, but kept getting this error.

So, I posted this question and went to make a burrito. I just came back, clicked save again and no error!

So the answer is to just wait for salesforce to not be bad.